# Add space between bar in multibarchart from nvd3

Tags: nvd3.js, spacing

How could I add some space between two bars from the same group, in NVD3 chart?
I try `chart.groupSpacing(0.5)` but nothing changes...

I can't put any pictures because I need at least 10 reputation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *groupSpacing* changes distance between groups of bars.

```
var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
    .groupSpacing(0.5)
    ;
```

I've created an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5bmbthwj/1/)

If you want to add space between bars within a particular group then you'll need to modify nvd3 source or write a multibar using pure d3.
This answer will be useful [How to add space between bars in a grouped bar chart in a nvd3 grouped multibar chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499347/how-to-add-space-between-bars-in-a-grouped-bar-chart-in-a-nvd3-grouped-multibar)

Comment: Yeah I want " add space between bars within a particular group" But I don't want modify nvd3 .... Thanks you anyway ovvn !

Comment: not available (yet) for multiBarHorizontalChart  https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/1058